# Can I use calc and var to change my div height based on its width?

Tags: css, calc

So let's say my divs `width` of `470px` is `100%` and `350px` is `0%` of `height`.
 From `100%` to `0%` I want my divs `height` to decrease from `100px` to `0px`.

Hope it's not too confusing...

Can it be done without javascript?

It's for an empty spacer div.

Comment: Basically i want the DIVs height to shrink as the width shrinks (proportionally)

Comment: `max-width: 470px; min-width: 350px; height: calc(100*(attr(width)-350)/120)` maybe?

Comment: What @Rafalon wrote with the help of [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) if you want to animate it

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, i would like it to happen when the viewport changes between those widths.

Comment: You can use `height: 0; padding-top: 10%` to have a height relative to the width. (1/10 in this example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmxXpO?editors=1100)

**CSS**

```
div {
   background: #9bc;
   max-width: 470px;
   min-width: 350px;
   max-height: 100px;
   height: calc(0.83333 * 100vw - 291.66px);
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

The height has been calculated with the [equation of the line passing from 2 points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation).

I show you the calculations so you will be able to change that expression as you prefer

[image]

Comment: Cheers, superb!

Comment: Or, well, `calc(100 * (100vw - 350px) / 120);` so you don't even have to bother about approximations

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little confusing but as per my understanding if you don't want to use JS then you can use calc function in CSS. Systex for same is below:-
`div{
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}`